# Spring unittest - rollback on exception

Tags: java, spring, transactions, persistence, rollback

I have this unit test and I would like to use it in this way:

- If there are no exceptions, then commit to DB.
- If there are exceptions, then rollback everything.

  ```
  @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
  @ContextConfiguration(locations = { "/config/myContext.xml" })
  public class transactionTest {

  ...

  @Test
  @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, timeout = 60000,rollbackFor={Exception.class})
  @Rollback(false)
  public void testPersitMySubmissionOnlyIfNoExceptionsArePresent() throws Exception {  
      Submission submission = createSubmission();
      submissionService.persistSubmission(submission); //persist to DB
      Long submissionId = submission.getId();


      System.out.println("");
      System.out.println("#" + submissionId + " submission created.");
      System.out.println("");

      throw new Exception("I'm a problem!!!!!!!!!!!!!!"); //it simulates a problem, then I expect a rollback.

  }

  private Submission createSubmission(){
      //create an instance of Submission
  }

  }
  ```

why the transaction is not rollbacked in the above case?
How can I write it to make that possible?

Comment: It's not possible to say what's wrong from the snippet of code you posted.  Post the entire class.  From what is posted, it looks mostly correct, but the @Transactional annotation is unnecessary.  Hopefully this class is extending AbstractTransactionalJUnit4SpringContextTests.

Comment: @hyness I added more context

Comment: if I remove @Transactional from the method signature nothing is stored in DB also if no exceptions are presents.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "/config/myContext.xml" })
public class TransactionTest extends AbstractTransactionalJUnit4SpringContextTests {

    @Test
    //@Rollback(false) 
    public void testPersitMySubmissionOnlyIfNoExceptionsArePresent() throws Exception {
        Submission submission = createSubmission();
        submissionService.persistSubmission(submission); // persist to DB
        Long submissionId = submission.getId();

        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("#" + submissionId + " submission created.");
        System.out.println("");

        throw new Exception("I'm a problem!!!!!!!!!!!!!!"); // it simulates a
                                                            // problem, then I
                                                            // expect a
                                                            // rollback.
        //  Commit the transcation programatically
        //  Will cause compile error as unreachable code after thrown exception
        TestTransaction.flagForCommit();
        TestTransaction.end();
    }

    private Submission createSubmission() {
        // create an instance of Submission
    }
}
```

**Edit:**  My understanding was this would work.  I have never personally wanted this behavior.  Tests should be in a known state, and by definition, committing test data violates that.  I cannot test this now, but you should be able to use the **TestTransaction** static methods to achieve the same result.  Sample updated.

Comment: I got this:

`2016-02-03 18:42:11,107  INFO [main] (TransactionalTestExecutionListener.java:272) - Began transaction (1): transaction manager [org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager@76e40e28]; rollback [false]

#1492 submission created.

2016-02-03 18:42:11,755  INFO [main] (TransactionalTestExecutionListener.java:292) - Committed transaction after test execution for test context [[TestContext@22c77657 testClass = transactionTest, locations = `....after there is the stacktrace of my exception.

Comment: I did what you suggested but I cannot find the TestTransaction object.  I tried to use `import org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TestTransaction;`  but the object cannot be found.

Comment: I could not find TestTransaction because my version of Spring is older than version 4.

Answer (score 0):

I solved using this approach:

```
import org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager;

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "/config/myContext.xml" })
public class transactionTest {

@Inject
PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager;

@Test
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, timeout = 60000,rollbackFor={Exception.class})
@Rollback(false)
public void testPersitMySubmissionOnlyIfNoExceptionsArePresent() throws Exception {  
    //instantiate the transaction manager programmatically
    DefaultTransactionDefinition definition = new DefaultTransactionDefinition();
    TransactionStatus transaction = transactionManager.getTransaction(definition);

    try {
    // persist data to DB
    Submission submission = createSubmission();
    submissionService.persistSubmission(submission); //persist to DB
    Long submissionId = submission.getId();


    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("#" + submissionId + " submission created.");
    System.out.println("");

    //simulate the problem
    raiseException()

    } catch(Exception e){

        //rollback the transaction
        transactionManager.rollback(transaction);
        return;
    }

    // if I'm here, I haven't got any exception, then I can commit
    transactionManager.commit(transaction);

}

private Submission createSubmission(){
    //create an instance of Submission
}


private void raiseException() throws Exception{
        throw new Exception("I'm a problem!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");
}

}
```